# how can I remove specific columns and sort

Tags: bash

I have a data like this

```
JW_ID   ECK number  B number    T Number    M K12   Conc(%) Yield(uM)   Yield(ug/ml)
JW0002  ECK0003       b0003        thrB       thrB    32        2.3         78
JW0003  ECK0004       b0004        thrC       thrC    18        1.7         78
JW0004  ECK0005       b0005        yaaX       yaaX    78        1.2         14
JW0005  ECK0006       b0006        yaaA        yaaA   7         2.4         71
JW0007  ECK0008       b0008        talB        talB   85        2.7         94
```

I am trying to remove two columns and B Number and M K12
then sort the file by ascending based on Conc(%)    Yield(uM)   Yield(ug/ml)

I run it as

```
bash myprogram.sh filename.txt
```

I have tried to make a bash but no success, I would appreciate any help

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
while read -r line; do
# reading each line
awk '{$3=$5=""; print $0}' filename
sort -k6,1 -k7,2 -k8,3 filename
echo $line
done < $filename
```

the expected output is like this

```
JW_ID   ECK number  T Number    Conc(%) Yield(uM)   Yield(ug/ml)
JW0005  ECK0006.        yaaA        7        2.4    71
JW0003  ECK0004.        thrC        18       1.7    78
JW0002  ECK0003         thrB        32       2.3    78
JW0004  ECK0005.        yaaX        78       1.2    14
JW0007  ECK0008         talB        85       2.7    94
```

Comment: your file is Tab separated columns?

Comment: @αғsнιη that is right tab delimited text

Comment: and expected output would be like what? is this what you want `<infile cut -f1,2,4,6- |sort -t $'\t' -k4,6n`? if yes, I will answer it

Comment: @αғsнιη  I just added an expected output but could you make it more general? imagine if I have 10 columns to sort. by and after those columns I still have other columns , you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

This **awk** should give the desired results:

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { print $1,$2,$4,$6,$7,$8 }' data | sort -nk 4,6
JW_ID   ECK number      T Number        Conc(%) Yield(uM)       Yield(ug/ml)
JW0005  ECK0006 yaaA    7       2.4     71
JW0003  ECK0004 thrC    18      1.7     78
JW0002  ECK0003 thrB    32      2.3     78
JW0004  ECK0005 yaaX    78      1.2     14
JW0007  ECK0008 talB    85      2.7     94
```

If your field count is much higher, here's a version with a range function:

usage: `rng([begin],[end])`

```
$ awk -F '\t' '
function rng(b,e,  i,d){ d=$b;
  for(i=b+1;i<e;i++){ d=d""OFS""$i }
  d=d""OFS""$e;
  return d
}
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{ print rng(1,2),$4,rng(6,8) }' data | sort -nk 4,6
```